# scikit learn LatentDirichletAllocation hangs after multiprocessing and url requests

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

Generally, my python code does following three steps

1. run multiprocess to scrape search results from search engine
2. scrape text from each url in the list(without multiprocessing) using python requests library
3. run fit_partial method of LDA class object from scikit learn library

The program runs fine when I only scraped total of 50~80 urls, but
when there are many urls,the program hangs at step 3 after finishing three to eight fit_partial method and printing logs

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
```

If I check process cpu usages, all python processes have zero cpu usages

When I divide above three steps into two python files(One python script doing step 1 and 2 and save the result as files using pickle dump and another script doing step 3 after loading the saved files), the second python file(which contains step 3) runs fine and causes no problem.

So, I ran two simulations.
In the first simulation I only omitting step 2. In the second Simulation only omitting step 1.
In each simulation I loaded saved result of step 1 and step 2, instead of running the actual step.

First simulation ran fine, but second simulation hanged.

Which gives conclusion that step 2 is causing step 3 to hang.
Bellow is the code for step 2. All results are added to a dictionary object that uses urls as keys

```
def parse_information(url):

print(url)

try:
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
except:
    raise Exception("requests exception")

obj_bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

meta_refresh = obj_bs.find("meta", {"http-equiv": "refresh"})

if meta_refresh is not None:
    refresh_url = meta_refresh["content"].lower().rsplit("url=")[1]
    rup = urlparse(refresh_url)
    if rup.netloc == "":
        up = urlparse(url)
        return parse_information(up.scheme + "://" + up.netloc + refresh_url)
    return parse_information(refresh_url)

meta_charset = obj_bs.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'meta' and 'charset' in tag.attrs)
http_equivs = obj_bs.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'meta' and 'http-equiv' in tag.attrs)

if meta_charset is not None:
    response.encoding = meta_charset["charset"]
elif len(http_equivs) > 0:
    content_charset = ""
    for http_equiv in http_equivs:
        if http_equiv["http-equiv"].lower() == "content-type":
            content_charset = http_equiv["content"]
            break
    if content_charset != "":
        parse_charset = content_charset.split("charset=")
        if len(parse_charset) > 1:
            response.encoding = parse_charset[1]
    else:
        response.encoding = "shift_jis"
else:
    response.encoding = "shift_jis"
obj_bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

info_dict = dict(title="", h1="", keywords="", description="", h2="")

tag_title = obj_bs.find("title")
info_dict["title"] = tag_title.text if tag_title is not None else ""

tag_h1 = obj_bs.find("h1")
info_dict["h1"] = tag_h1.text if tag_h1 is not None else ""

tags_h2 = obj_bs.findAll("h2")
info_dict["h2"] = "|".join([tag_h2.text.strip("\t\r\n ") for tag_h2 in tags_h2]) if len(tags_h2) > 0 else ""

metas = obj_bs.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'meta' and 'name' in tag.attrs)

for meta in metas:
    if meta["name"] == "keywords":
        info_dict["keywords"] = meta.get("content", "")
    elif meta["name"] == "description":
        info_dict["description"] = meta.get("content", "")

htot = html2text.HTML2Text()
htot.ignore_links = True
htot.images_to_alt = True
htot.ignore_emphasis = True

pure_text = htot.handle(response.text).lower()

noun_dict = japanese_noun_dict(pure_text)

if len(noun_dict) == 0:
    num_nouns = 0
else:
    num_nouns = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, noun_dict.values())

return {"info": info_dict, "noun": {"num": num_nouns, "freq": noun_dict}}
```

Bellow is code for step 3. g_result_lda.model is scikit-learn LatentDirichletAllocation class object. corpus_data is document-word matrix created from the url texts

```
g_result_lda = TextLDA(documents=corpus_data, n_topics=n_topic)

len_corpus = len(g_result_lda.corpus_data)

# g_result_lda.model.fit(g_result_lda.corpus_data)

start_index = 0

while start_index < len_corpus:

    end_index = start_index + 20 if start_index + 20 < len_corpus else len_corpus
    g_result_lda.model.partial_fit(g_result_lda.corpus_data[start_index:end_index])
    start_index = start_index +20
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the problem?
Does scikit-learn Library have conflict with requests library?

I am learning python on OSX

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by constructing RPC server with RabbitMQ. 
I used Pika library to use RabbitMQ, and made a server with BlockingConnection. The server runs solely on one thread and process while waiting for one request and when it receives  a request it does LDA analysis with multi processing and returns the result.